# Big Query - Invalid credential at Util.parseHttpRespBody from nodejs application deployed in GKE

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a node js application that exposes rest endpoints that is accessible via cloud endpoint. While firing the endpoint url, node js executes big query and returns results. Everything is working fine I deployed it in compute engine. Since I am using same service account where big query datasets are available, so I am not adding "service-account-key.json" file. Only explicitely mentioning Location of the dataset where the query will be executed i.e. 'EU'.

But after the deployment in GKE I have got following errors, only for those end points whichs are accessing Big Query. Error is:

I have enabled big query apis before trying it, as I have mentioned it works from compute engine as a sample development platform before containerizing it.

```
ERROR: ApiError: Invalid credential at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:190:38) at Util.handleResp (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:134:117) at /app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:422:22 at onResponse (/app/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7) at /app/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:222:13 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5) {
```

next line of stack driver:

```
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "      domain: 'global',
```

and

```
locationType: 'other',
```

Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Regards,
Arindam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I am using same service account where big query datasets are available, so I am not adding "service-account-key.json" file.

Your problem is that you **MUST** provide the service account file key
Below find a working node.js Mocha test example which accesses BigQuery and performs a select.

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
    var a = require("babel-polyfill")
}

    import BigQuery from '@google-cloud/bigquery'

    describe('Check google-cloud', async () => {

        it('Test query', async () => {
            let result = await test('panada')

        })

        async function test(p1) {
            try {
                const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                    projectId: `mydata`,
                    keyFilename: 'mydata-1470162410749-9473b308ab0e.json'
                })

                let query = [
                    'SELECT url',
                    'FROM `publicdata.samples.github_nested`',
                    'WHERE repository.owner = @owner'

                ].join(' ')

                console.log(`query is: ${query}`)
                let [result] = await bigquery.query({
                    query,
                    params: {
                        owner: p1
                    }
                })

                result.forEach((row, index) => {
                    console.log(`row number ${index}, url is: ${row.url}`)
                })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("err", err)
            }
        }
    })
```

The output of this code is:

```
row number 0, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/46934664ea...a7cae9f088
    row number 1, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/compare/47a1801f13...9dedbc8ce6
    row number 2, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/a7cae9f088...256c9b4ed3
    row number 3, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/pull/36
    row number 4, url is: https://github.com/de3/Panada
    row number 5, url is: https://github.com/schbern/samples
    row number 6, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/compare/175c88e2cb...47a1801f13
    row number 7, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/256c9b4ed3...1f293ca245
    row number 8, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/compare/49c38b23e2...d948d2eb97
    row number 9, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/pull/38
    row number 10, url is: https://github.com/panada/samples/compare/1a35a44548...46934664ea
    row number 11, url is: https://github.com/de3/documentation
    row number 12, url is: https://github.com/cakyus/Panada
    row number 13, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/compare/46b7bcde5f...52e9ef5c67
    row number 14, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/issues/1#issuecomment-4533276
    row number 15, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/compare/d948d2eb97...46b7bcde5f
    row number 16, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/compare/9dedbc8ce6...4db3e50d80
    row number 17, url is: https://github.com/panada/Panada/pull/38
    row number 18, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/pull/1
    row number 19, url is: https://github.com/panada/documentation/pull/1
```

Comment: Hi Tamir, Thanks a lot. In that case, my docker image will vary from DEV to QA to PROD, no? A command be passed through an argument in Kubernetes Deployment YML file, but how can a complete file be handled dynamically? as manual intervention is required to be avoided.

Comment: The image has nothing to do with your service account file which you can deploy on all machines into a predefined path. Note: In BigQuery there is no dev/prod etc what is typically done is using dataset for each environment or a project depanding on your use case. If you need different service accounts simply define them on the matching docker. Hope this makes sense to you.